# Flash inactive tab in ConEmu (like Console does)

Tags: command-line, conemu, console2

Is there a setting on ConEmu similar to the "Flash inactive tabs" setting in the Console app?

When I run three scripts in three different tabs in ConEmu I would like either of the two tabs that are currently not 'in front' (inactive) to blink/flash/highlight/alert me somehow when something new has printed within them.

Console calls this 'Flash inactive tabs' in their similar app.  I'd like to move to ConEmu because it seems to be more powerful/feature packed generally, though as far as I can tell via experimentation and research it lacks this feature which is important to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Feature is available since build [141123](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Whats_New#Build_141123).